# How to access a Microservice's Socket through Gateway

Tags: java, websocket, playframework, microservices

I have a few microservices(Play + Spring Boot) that I access through the Gateway (Play). I need to write a socket in a microservice (with the data) in the Play framework for the user notifications and access it through the Gateway.

Could anyone suggest the best way to implement such a use case?
Whether it would be better to have the socket in the Gateway and poll the microservice for changes or access the socket URL through Gateway or anything as such.

Thanks in advance.